# Edit pages content through a UI

Tags: user-interface, content-management-system, admin, edit

Sorry if someone already did this question, but I couldn't find it. I want to allow my client to edit the website pages content through a UI, not using notepad++ or something like that, you know? Like edit the FAQ or add some new product to his store. I don't know how to search it. I already looked for admin dashboard templates, but nothing...

Comment: Is it server-side or all client-side?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot about this. I'll write up an answer now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you want a CMS (Content Management System). This would allow you to run a website with an editor and many other tools to help you and your clients out with development. Popular CMS's even have large libraries of plugins to customize and add virtually anything to the development environment. Popular CMS's include:

- WordPress
- Drupal
- Joomla
- ModX
- etc.

You can even develop your own via PHP and MySQL databasing. Not only does this allow you to have the tools tailored to your needs, but it's also a great learning experience.

If you're looking for just a sort of online IDE (Integrated Development Environment), then Cloud9 may suit your needs, but it can get pricy depending on what you need: https://c9.io/

Overall, if you're dealing with dozens of HTML documents on a website, it can get messy and the need to switch to templating is an absolute necessity. CMS's are easy to install and have a lot of features, but they can be very bulky. So if you're just looking for a simple management system, I think PHP and MySQL would be best for your scenario. If that's all you want then here are some articles to get you started:

- https://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/
- http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/getting-started-with-php-templating/

Comment: Actually I already built (sorry for bad english). Everything is done, but my client often ask for some little modifications. And I don't want to make it forever, you know? Add some Admin Panel where he could edit texts and thing without care about HTML. Like some system integrated with some kind of WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: In that case you're more limited to Cloud9 or a CMS. Anything else would be beyond the scope of Stack Overflow's Q&A format.